# how to return anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
             function test(){                   
                 return function(){
                  alert("hi");
                }                
             }
             test();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my code, can I ask why it doesnt work properly??

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: what do you want to return here?

Comment: i just want testing around javascript and learn how it works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you're returning your function but not invoking it.
Try this:

```
test()();
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zKaES/)

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be confused. `test()` returns a function reference, but it won't execute it.

You could do something like this

```
var alertFunc = test(); // return function reference
alertFunc(); // call the function
```

Comment: this is better for sure ;)